# Python Matplotlib pyplot colorbar indices

Tags: python, matplotlib, indices, colorbar

I want to plot a bivariate normal distribution and have been looking through the Matplotlib's pylab examples for guidance. However, for some reason, I have trouble reproducing one of its graphs: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_log.html

The code seems simple enough, but when I copy/paste/run it, it produces a plot with most of the colorbar display values missing.

[image]

Furthermore, comparing to the example, mine also has a larger range, going as low as 1e-6 (rather than 1e-5). So now I'm wondering if my matplotlib package is faulty and requires re-installation/update. Please let me know where the error may lie. Thanks!

**Additional info**

Python version: 
'2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (32-bit)| (r271:86832, Dec  3 2010, 15:41:32) \n[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)]'

OS:
Mac OS X: 10.6.8

Matplotlib version:
1.0.1

Also, my Matplotlib backend is set to TKAgg.

I'm a little wary of re-installing Matplotlib since I'm currently mainly running Python under FiPy and it took ages to get everything running relatively smoothly..

Comment: I just successfully reproduced the graph on matplotlib's site.  Matplotlib has been difficult to set up for me in the past, so reinstalling it could definitely be worth it.  If that doesn't work or you want more help first, can you give us some more info about your problem?  Operating system, python version, and matplotlib version would all be helpful.

Comment: With matplotlib '1.1.0' you would get the same image as in the example.
Try to specify your min and max z, by changing the the countourf line to: `cs = P.contourf(X, Y, z, locator=ticker.LogLocator(), vmin=1E-5, vmax=1E1)` and then change the colorbar line to `cbar = P.colorbar(cs)` and see if you can get it now.